# Failed to find a suitable device for the type IBSimDeviceTypeiPad2x

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, ios12, xcode10.3

After updating to Xcode Version 10.3 (10G8) I started seeing this error. Errors like this are usual, so I restarted the program, but it is still there:

```
/* com.apple.actool.errors */
/Users/si/Developer/ImmoWert2Go/ios/iw2go/Images.xcassets: error: Failed to find a suitable device for the type IBSimDeviceTypeiPad2x (com.apple.dt.Xcode.IBSimDeviceType.iPad-2x) with runtime iOS 12.4 (12.4 - 16G73) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-4
    Failure Reason: Failed to create new simulator device that matches IBSimDeviceTypeiPad2x (com.apple.dt.Xcode.IBSimDeviceType.iPad-2x) for runtime iOS 12.4 (12.4 - 16G73) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-4 (Invalid runtime: com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-4)
    Underlying Errors:
        Description: Invalid runtime: com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-12-4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same issue, and managed to solve it by killing emulators processes :

```
sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorDevice
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a common problem after updating Xcode, when Simulator was running on the previous version.

The solution is to kill the simulator service process. (The service name changed at some point.) The current command is:

```
sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService
```

Answer (score 0):

It's apparently a common problem that everyone has after updating to Xcode 10.3.

Restarting the computer solves it.